# Create environment variable from parameters in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkinsfile which is parametrized. Based on the input parameters I want to set certain environment variables. But I m not able to get the syntax right.

```
parameters {
    choice choices: ['insure-base-docker/insure-base', 'insure-ide/insure-sd', 'insure-ide/insure-ansible','insure-ide/ansible-test-vini'], description: 'Auf welche repository sollte die Tag erstellt?', name: 'repository'
    choice choices: ['tag', 'branch'], description: 'Tag oder branch erstellen', name: 'git_entity'
    string defaultValue: '21.x.x', description: 'Version die als branch oder Tag ersellt werden muss', name: 'version', trim: false
}
environment {
    GIT_URL = "${'https://my_repo/scm/'+param.repository+'.git'}"
    GIT_BRANCH = "${'Release/'+param.version}"
    CHECKOUT_BRANCH = '${${git_entity} == "tag" ? "master" : "develop"}'      
}
```

the env vars are always wrong. How do I set the env vars correctly?

Comment: You have a typo in your `environment` directive: the object is `params` and not `param`.

Comment: this i corrected in my real file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nowadays, there aren't many differences between parameters and environment variables in Jenkins. Even the way you use them, preceded by the `env.` keyword, is the same.

Try something like this.

```
pipeline {
    parameters {
      choice choices: ['insure-base-docker/insure-base', 'insure-ide/insure-sd', 'insure-ide/insure-ansible','insure-ide/ansible-test-vini'], description: 'Auf welche repository sollte die Tag erstellt?', name: 'GIT_PROJECT'
      string defaultValue: '21.x.x', description: 'Version die als branch oder Tag ersellt werden muss', name: 'GIT_BRANCH', trim: false
    }

    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Cloning Git repository') {
            steps {
                script {
                    git branch: "${env.GIT_BRANCH}", credentialsId: 'MY_GIT_CREDENTIALS_PREVIOUSLY_ADDED_TO_JENKINS', url: "http://github.com/user/${env.GIT_PROJECT}.git"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can use as `GIT_BRANCH` not just branches, but also tags.

Best regards.

Comment: Do you see in the env section in the code, i have env variables as a string in conjunction to the params

Comment: and also the above doesnt work with variables. I have an echo which prints the value, its right from my env, but the usage of git with vars isnt working

Comment: error: > git config --get remote.${GIT_URL_STEP}.url # timeout=10
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from ${GIT_URL_STEP}

Comment: the double quotes was important

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using a freestyle project
here are the steps

1. Go to Build Environment part and check the option Inject environment variables to the build process
   it will open a new set of input boxes.
2. enter your code in Groovy script

Here am just trying to update the Version and Full version to include the passing parameter say TestParam

here is a sample:

```
import hudson.model.*
import groovy.io.FileType

def build = Thread.currentThread().executable
def buildNumber = build.number
def workspace = build.getEnvVars()["WORKSPACE"]
def defaultBuildNo = build.getEnvVars()["BUILD_NUMBER"]
println "Hi from Groovy script "
println workspace
println defaultBuildNo

def map = [
                 "BUILD_NUMBER": defaultBuildNo,
                 "VERSION" : defaultBuildNo + build.getEnvVars()["TestParam"],
                 "FULL_VERSION": +defaultBuildNo + "." + build.getEnvVars(["TestParam"]
                ]
return map
```

Now in the execute shell part type these and see all will resolve successfully.

Execute shell

```
 echo $TestParam
 echo $BUILD_NUMBER
 echo $VERSION
 echo $FULL_VERSION
```

Now all these env variables are accessible throughout the Job.

Answer (score 1):

I had to map the param to env in the stage:

```
pipeline {
    parameters {
      choice choices: ['insure-base-docker/insure-base', 'insure-ide/insure-sd', 'insure-ide/insure-ansible','insure-ide/ansible-test-vini'], description: 'Auf welche repository sollte die Tag erstellt?', name: 'GIT_PROJECT'
      string defaultValue: '21.x.x', description: 'Version die als branch oder Tag ersellt werden muss', name: 'GIT_BRANCH', trim: false
    }

    stages {
        stage('Cloning Git repository') {
            environment {
                GIT_PROJECT = "${params.GIT_PROJECT}"
                GIT_BRANCH = "${params.GIT_BRANCH}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I can access the parameters as environment variables in other scripts that can only use environment variables.